# Download and setup a Angular/Django site from server to localhost?

Tags: python, angularjs, django, web-services, postgresql

Hi I am new to Django and have been googling for a whole day without any success.

Basically there is a live/working website built with AngularJS, Django and PostgreSQL (Ubuntu 14.04) and I am trying to download all the files and clone the site into my localhost (Ubuntu 14.04).

After I downloaded the folder and finished install the required packages on my localhost, I run:
`python manage.py makemigrations`

`python manage.py migrate`

`python manage.py runserver`

The server runs without reporting any errors. 
However, some of the links are directed to a 404 page, such as this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/city/chicago
```

Whereas in the live site, it would direct to the correct working page.

Can someone tell me what may have gone wrong in the process?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you grab a sqldump as well? If not, one thing that can cause this is just "the live server has data and you don't". Look in the view for that URL; does it `raise Http404` anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try editing the settings.py file set the `DEBUG` value to `True`. Instead of a 404 you should get a full debug of the actual request and see what exactly is missing (I suspect missing data as @NightShadeQueen pointed).

Also you might have a look at [django debug toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar) which prints the executed sql queries as well and run them against your local database to see what exactly they return.